# Working of Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I recently learned that we can't access `inner function` directly. We need to make the object of the function to do that. However it looks different to me in `Date` function since we can access inner functions like `Date.now()`.`typeof Date` returns `"function"` and not `"Object"`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by "inner function"?

Comment: "Methods" are distinct from "inner functions". By definition, methods are exposed on the object on which they are defined.

Comment: thanks @torazaburo for the great comment. I guess my entire confusion is between methods and inner functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a such thing. Here `b` function is a function of the `A`.
Typeof `A` will return `function`. But in `Javascript` functions are also objects. So you can add `properties` and `functions`(`methods`) to the `function object itself`.

```js
function A(){
  
}

A.b = function(){
  console.log('B');
}

A.b();
```

But if you mean inner function to this

```js
function A(){
  
  function b(){
    console.log('b')  ;
  }
  
}
```

You can't access the inner `b` function outside the `A` .

One case to access the inner function outside the `A`, you need to assign the function to the `this`, which is called `method`, then create an object of `A` and use that `method`.

```js
function A(){
      
  this.b = function (){
    console.log('b');
  };
      
}

let a = new A();
a.b();
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. Could you please elaborate on difference between first and second way. To me both look same.

Comment: @SKG in the first case I assign the function to the `A`'s `b` property.It will be part of `A`. In the second case it is only a function in the `A`'s scope. It is not a part of any object.

Comment: "But in Javascript functions are also objects". Can you tell me how can I look up this object? Printing function name in console just gives function definition, not Function object.

Comment: In the browser's console log A.prototype, and in the constructor you will see the object

Answer (score -1):

Actually, `Date` is the constructor of the Object `Date`,
so it is a common sense that you use `new Date()` to get access into these 'inner functions' you referred in your question:

```
type of Date // function
type of Date() // string, shorthand of new Date().toString()
type of new Date() // object
```

Comment: How can something be a constructor and an object at the same time (which isn’t even the case)? How is a function property something specific to constructors (which it isn’t)? What does this have to do with `new`? How does this answer the question for `Date.now` which is invalid with `new`?

Comment: @Xufox Date is not only a Object but also the constructor of Date. You can use `new` to create an instance of a Date object. Please read more reference at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date  Do not ask these simple questions that you can just Google it.

Comment: Can you name an example of a function or constructor that doesn’t behave like an object? What does your reply have to do with the question or the concerns in my first comment? Again, what does `new` have to do with function properties?

Answer (score -1):

The inner function mostly is a constructor Function.

e.g: 
    
    `function MyDate () {
    }
    MyDate.prototype.getDate = function () {
        console.log('getDate')
    }
    MyDate.getDate() // getDate`